# Parse error raw string and select a error type efficiently

Tags: php, parsing, optimization

So I've the following situation: A process is piping huge amounts of data into a PHP script I'm using to parse and then store some info in a DB.

The input data is a multiline string, but what really matters for me is to find particular key words and then say that the input data is an error of the type 1 to n.

I've an array like this:

```
$errors = [ 
1 => [
        "error 4011",
        "clp-no",

     ],
2 => [
        "error 4012",
        "clp-nf",
        "0010x100"
     ],
];
```

The idea is to state what key is the error - the array keys are the error numbers. Currently I've this piece of code to take care of the situation:

```
$errorId = 25; // Default error for undetected / others
foreach ($errors as $ierrorId => $matches) {
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        if (mb_stripos($raw, $match) !== false) {
            $errorId = $ierrorId;
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine, however, it looks like there is a bottleneck when I look at resource usage when the processes dump information to it... (usually around 10 or 20 strings to be processed by running that 20 times.)

What is the recommended way to do what I'm trying to accomplish with the minimum resource usage?

---

The output of the code is the ID of the error. The ID of the error is one of the numeric keys of the `$errors` array.

This code basically groups possible messages that are in the reality the same error and then gives me a unique error ID.

### Thank you.

Example of the `$raw` input this parses:

```
[0]: error 4011 processing request
```

.

```
No input data: clp-nf
```

.

```
This is an automated message from the PTD daemon 
    => Error: 0010x111.
```

And some others, the bottom line is: The format can change and I can't rely on position and stuff, it must try to find one of the strings on the array and then return the array key. For instance the second message will output `2` because `clp-nf` can be found on the second position of the array.

Comment: Does your script actually have the line `$errorId = $errorId;`?

Comment: @ialarmedalien actually it did! It still worked because the last error in the array has the key value of `25`. I fixed it anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Could you add the output that you want to get from each error (i.e. what gets written to the database)?

Comment: What is `$raw`? Can you also say what the expected output from the array of sample errors is? I don't quite understand whether you're just trying to pull the 'error nnnn' line from the arrays or if it's something else.

Comment: I'm trying to pull the array key, the 'error nnnn' is what `$raw` might have.

Comment: `$raw` is not initialised (at least not in the code you've posted) so the `mb_stripos` function isn't returning anything.

Comment: `$raw` is the script input, initialized previously.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I had got things the wrong way around--I thought that you were checking the array, but you're checking `$raw`. Could you paste an example of `$raw` with several different errors in it, and the expected output from your error checker?

Comment: The `$raw` can be any format, thats the tricky part, the only think I can assure is that it might contain one of the error descriptions like `error 4012` present on the array. The script output for that case would be `2` because the `error 4012` in on the second array key.

Comment: Could you add some samples of `$raw` to the Q for testing purposes? I assume you are also searching for strings like `clp-no` and `0010x100`, and you expect there only to be one error per `$raw` - right? Do you know what encoding `$raw` will be in? `mb_stripos` is significantly slower than `stripos`, so if you can use `stripos`, you should.

Comment: "you expect there only to be one error per `$raw`" -- yes. Encoding UTF8 that's why I'm using `mb_` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little benchmarking with different functions to find text strings.

- `mb_stripos` (case insensitive)
- `mb_strpos` (case sensitive)
- `mb_strpos` and `strtolower` on both the string to be searched and the error strings

I also tried the nested array structure you posted above, and a flat error list with the keys being the error strings and the values being the error number. Here are the results I got from running 20,000 reps on a set of sample strings (all returned the same set of errors) with an array of six different error strings, including one error string with non-ASCII characters:

```
[nested_stripos] => 178.60633707047s
[nested_strpos] => 19.614015340805s
[nested_strpos_with_strtolower] => 25.815476417542s
[flat_stripos] => 177.30470108986s
[flat_strpos] => 18.139512062073s
[flat_strpos_with_strtolower] => 24.32790517807s
```

As you can see, using `mb_stripos` is very slow in comparison with `mb_strpos`. If you don't know what case the errors will be in, it is much quicker to convert everything to lowercase than to use `mb_stripos`.  Using a flat list is marginally faster than the nested arrays over 20,000 reps but there is unlikely to be a noticeable difference unless your raw input is large.

I didn't test `preg_match` as it is fairly well known that regular expressions are slower than string matching.

If you start recording the error string that was matched (e.g. `error 4012` or `0010x001`), you can build up frequency tables and order your error strings by which occur the most frequently.

This was the fastest function:

```
# lines: an array of text strings, including several with non-ASCII characters
# $err_types: data structure holding the error messages to search for (see below)
function flat_strpos($err_types, $lines){
    $list = array();
    foreach ($lines as $l) {
        $err = 25;
        foreach ($err_types['flat'] as $e => $no) {
            if (mb_strpos($l, $e) !== false) {
                $err = $no;
                break;
            }
        }
        $list[] = "ERR $err; content: " . mb_substr($l, 0, 100);
    }
    return $list;
}
```

And for reference, the `$err_type` data structure:

```
$err_types = [
    'flat' => [
        'error 4011' => 1,
        'clp-no' => 1,
        'error 4012' => 2,
        'clp-nf' => 2,
        '0010x100' => 2,
        '颜色' => 3
    ],
    'nested' => [
        1 => [
            'error 4011',
            'clp-no'
        ],
        2 => [
            'error 4012',
            'clp-nf',
            '0010x100'
        ],
        3 => [
            '颜色'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: `build up frequency tables and order your error strings by which occur the most frequently` -- good tip, that will even speed this up more on the long run! Thank you.